# Isolating variable in exponents in a linear combination of exponential functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I'm doing a physics problem that's asking me to compare the maximum speeds of a simple harmonic oscillator versus one immersed in a fluid that's leading to overdamping. I am at a point where I have the velocity solution: $$\dot x(t) = \frac{-\omega^{2}x_0}{2\Omega}[e^{-(\gamma - \Omega) t} - e^{-(\gamma + \Omega)t}]$$ Where $$\Omega = \sqrt{\gamma^{2} - \omega^2}$$ All Greek letters are constants. From here I'd like to differentiate and set the second derivative equal to zero then solve for $t$ to determine the time in which the velocity is at a maximum then plug that back in to the equation for the velocity to determine the maximum velocity. I'm having trouble solving for $t$ and would like some assistance if possible. The second derivative is then: $$\ddot x(t) = \frac{-\omega^{2}x_0}{2\Omega}[-(\gamma - \Omega)e^{-(\gamma - \Omega) t} + (\gamma + \Omega)e^{-(\gamma + \Omega)t}] = 0$$ From here I know if I want to solve for $t$ then I'll need to employ the natural logarithm to "pull" the $t$ from the exponent down to the base however I'm confused on a few fronts, namely:

1. Would I be applying the natural log to the entire function or could I selectively apply it only to the 2 exponential functions?
2. Furthermore, would I need to apply the natural log to both sides of the equation (as if I was multiplying one side by a constant?). Then I would get a $-\infty$ on the RHS and that doesn't seem right.

I appreciate any help in elucidating the way in which one would work with logarithms to help isolate the variable in question here.

Comment: Do some algebra to get the equation into the form $\exp(a t) = b$, where hopefully $b > 0$. Then take the log of both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I be applying the natural log to the entire function or could I
> selectively apply it only to the 2 exponential functions?

The log of a sum does not help much. But you can firstly factor out $e^{-(\gamma - \Omega)t}$

$$e^{-(\gamma - \Omega) t}\cdot\frac{-\omega^{2}x_0}{2\Omega}[-(\gamma - \Omega) + (\gamma + \Omega)e^{-2\Omega t}] = 0$$

Now we use the following rule: *A product is zero, if at least one of the factors is zero.*

With some assumption we can say that the factors $e^{-(\gamma - \Omega) t}$ and $\frac{-\omega^{2}x_0}{2\Omega}$ cannot be zero. Thus the bracket must be zero.

$-(\gamma - \Omega) + (\gamma + \Omega)e^{-2\Omega t}=0$

$ (\gamma + \Omega)e^{-2\Omega t}=(\gamma - \Omega) $

$ e^{-2\Omega t}=\frac{\gamma - \Omega}{\gamma + \Omega} $

Now you can take logs.

Comment: Perfect I ended up getting $$t_{\text{max}} = \frac{1}{2\Omega} \ln[\frac{\gamma + \Omega}{\gamma - \Omega}]$$ which ended up working out to the correct answer in the back of the book. Thanks for the help. The extending of the log over the sum was what really tripped me up. If I see something like that in the future I'll try and isolate a single variable in the exponent with some nonzero quantity on the other side of the equation.

Comment: @NumericalDisintegration You're welcome. It always depends on the problem which method works. Now you have your way for problems where  the log term is no sum. And for this kind problems factoring out can be a good way. The more cases you're facing, the more "methods" you will learn.